# Send email in Android with Java

Tags: java, android

I created this snippet to send email by clicking on a Preference of my android application. But I want to put in the email the phone features (such as the name of the mobile phone, the version of Android, etc.) which sends the email, using the Build class. How can I do? Here's what I've done until now.

```
Preference Email;

Email = (Preference) this.findPreference("email");
Email.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        // Informazioni sul telefono
        String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
        String model = Build.MODEL;
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        String[] recipients = new String[]{"" , "EMAIL@gmail.com"};
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "" );
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Email"));
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your **phone features** data into the code

> emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, YOUR_PHONE_FEATURES_STRING);

So your code will be like below:

```
Preference Email;

Email = (Preference) this.findPreference("email");
Email.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        // Informazioni sul telefono
        String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
        String model = Build.MODEL;

        //**EDITED**
        String STR_EMAIL_BODY = "Manufacturer: "+manufacturer + "\nModel: " + model;

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        String[] recipients = new String[]{"" , "EMAIL@gmail.com"};
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "" );
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, STR_EMAIL_BODY);
        //**EDITED**
        intent.setType("text/html");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Email"));
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks ... but because if I put emailIntent.putExtra (android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, manufacturer, model);
  I get an error? How do I put more string?

Comment: you can make one string with "\n" character. because EXTRA_TEXT is your body text so you need to put one formatted string in to that parameter.\

Comment: and you can not enter more strings? I would like to put at least the name of the mobile phone and the version of Android. I have trie with:         emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, manufacturer \n model);
 but do not work

Comment: check my edited answer. you need to setType with "text/html".

Comment: Anytime John...:-) you can make upvote any answer that you feel is useful to other users.

Comment: last thing ... how do I know which version of Android you have (using the class build)?